# laravel eloquent update hasmany with array of ids

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I need to update `HasMany` relation with set of id's.

**Faq model.**

```
class Faq extends Model
{
   public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'faq_products');
   }
}
```

I have `Product` model and pivot table 'faq_products' for `HasMany` relation.

**faq_products table**

```
    Schema::create('faq_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('faq_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('faq_id')->references('id')->on('faqs')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And I'm getting an array of product ids from request related to faq but not sure how to update the relationship.

array

```
$product_ids = [4, 3, 2];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet, it's [`attach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching) you're looking for:

```
class FaqController extends Controller
{
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $faq = Faq::findOrFail($request->input('faq_id');
        //attached products [4,5,6]
        $faq->products()->attach($request->input('product_ids')); // [4, 3, 2];
        //attached products [2,3,4,5,6]
    }
}
```

If you have previously attached other products (example id = 4, 5 and 6) and you want to remove them while attaching 4, 3 and 2; use [`sync()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations) instead of attach

```
//attached products [4,5,6]
$faq->products()->sync($request->input('product_ids')); // product_ids = [4,3,2]
//attached products [4,3,2]
```

Comment: @vimuth use `input()` method for data, and `findOrFail()` for exception (in case the id doesnt exist) it will return a 404

Comment: @N69S improved the answer significantly.